# How can I use Ubuntu live with a newer kernel?

Tags: boot, kernel

I've just bought a new Acer Aspire notebook with AMD Ryzen 5 CPU and Radeon GPU and my ubuntu 18.04 liveUSB doesn't start. The boot is okay but the kernel freezes with this message: AMD-Vi: Disabling interrupt remapping.

I found that this happens because older kernel doesn't support new amd stuffs so I would like to know how could I boot an Ubuntu install with the newer 4.17 kernel.

I tried to load the proper 4.17 image using grub(liveusb) command line  but ls command doesn't do anything and so I can't find drives/partitions.

Does somebody have a solution for this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ubuntu live (generally linux live) systems can only use the kernel, that comes with the iso file.

But you can get a newer iso file from the [QA iso testing tracker](http://iso.qa.ubuntu.com/). There are daily iso files of 'Bionic' alias 18.04 LTS (which develops slowly and in a stable way) and of 'Cosmic' to be released as 18.10 in October.

You can check if one of these daily iso files will work. I don't know know any other [easy] way to get Ubuntu live with a newer kernel.

Comment: Daily builds you can find [here](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com)